# How to use variables for storing values in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to check that the length of DOM element would remain at submit of the whole page

my code:

```
let count_luok = cy.get('#luok_table').children('tbody').first().children('tr').length
// clicking all_in_one_save-button stores the page
cy.get('[id=all_in_one_save]').click()
cy.wait(5000)   
cy.get('#luok_table').children('tbody').first().children('tr').should('have.length',`${count_luok}`)
```

When running the code Cypress informs:

```
CypressError: You must provide a valid number to a `length` assertion. You passed: `undefined`
```